# which isopackager/channel is more appropriate to set balance inquiries with JPOS?

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I have that query to make :

```
 "dataFields":{
    "F2_PrimaryAccountNumber":"0009042120770050819",
    "F3_ProcessingCode":"319999",
    "F4_AmountTransaction":"000000000000",
    "F11_SystemTraceAuditNumber" : "745609",
    "F12_LocalTransactionTime": "230303165345",
    "F15_SettlementDate" : "230303",
    "F18_MerchantType" : "5311",
    "F22_PointOfServiceEntryMode":"200101200000",
    "F23_ApplicationPANSequenceNumber":"1",
    "F32_AcquiringInstitutionIdCode":"243111",
    "F37_RetrievalReferenceNumber":"103847124152",
    "F41_CardAcceptor_TerminalID":"00000002",
    "F42_CardAcceptor_IDCode":"000000000000001",
    "F43_CardAcceptorInfo":"colombia985macampagne",
    "F48_AdditionalData_Private":"7020876567098",
    "F100_ReceivingInstitutionIdentificationCode":"90236529067"
},
```

it's a json which i transform into ISO 8583 frame.
the Message type is 1200 but i receive a response which is incoherent. (1804 instead of 1210).

here is my packager :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
        "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
        "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">

<!-- ISO 8583:1993 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->

<isopackager>
  <isofield
          id="0"
          length="4"
          name="Message Type Indicator"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="1"
          length="16"
          name="Bitmap"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BITMAP"/>
  <isofield
          id="2"
          length="19"
          name="Primary Account number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="3"
          length="6"
          name="Processing Code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="4"
          length="12"
          name="Amount, Transaction"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="5"
          length="12"
          name="Amount, Reconciliation"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="6"
          length="12"
          name="Amount, Cardholder billing"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="7"
          length="10"
          name="Date and time, transmission"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="8"
          length="8"
          name="Amount, Cardholder billing fee"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="9"
          length="8"
          name="Conversion rate, Reconciliation"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="10"
          length="8"
          name="Conversion rate, Cardholder billing"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="11"
          length="6"
          name="Systems trace audit number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="12"
          length="12"
          name="Date and time, Local transaction"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="13"
          length="4"
          name="Date, Effective"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="14"
          length="4"
          name="Date, Expiration"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="15"
          length="6"
          name="Date, Settlement"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="16"
          length="4"
          name="Date, Conversion"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="17"
          length="4"
          name="Date, Capture"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="18"
          length="4"
          name="Merchant type"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="19"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, Acquiring institution"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="20"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, Primary account number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="21"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, Forwarding institution"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="22"
          length="12"
          name="Point of service data code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="23"
          length="3"
          name="Card sequence number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="24"
          length="3"
          name="Function code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="25"
          length="4"
          name="Message reason code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="26"
          length="4"
          name="Card acceptor business code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="27"
          length="1"
          name="Approval code length"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="28"
          length="6"
          name="Date, Reconciliation"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="29"
          length="3"
          name="Reconciliation indicator"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="30"
          length="24"
          name="Amounts, original"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="31"
          length="99"
          name="Acquirer reference data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="32"
          length="11"
          name="Acquirer institution identification code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="33"
          length="11"
          name="Forwarding institution identification code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="34"
          length="28"
          name="Primary account number, extended"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="35"
          length="37"
          name="Track 2 data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="36"
          length="104"
          name="Track 3 data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="37"
          length="12"
          name="Retrieval reference number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="38"
          length="6"
          name="Approval code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="39"
          length="3"
          name="Action code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="40"
          length="3"
          name="Service code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="41"
          length="8"
          name="Card acceptor terminal identification"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="42"
          length="15"
          name="Card acceptor identification code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="43"
          length="99"
          name="Card acceptor name/location"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="44"
          length="99"
          name="Additional response data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="45"
          length="76"
          name="Track 1 data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="46"
          length="204"
          name="Amounts, Fees"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="47"
          length="999"
          name="Additional data - national"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofieldpackager
          id="48"
          length="255"
          name="Additional Data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"
          emitBitmap="false"
          firstField="2"
          packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericSubFieldPackager">
    <isofield
            id="2"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="3"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="4"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="5"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="6"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="7"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="8"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="9"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="10"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="11"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield
            id="12"
            length="8"
            name="first field"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  </isofieldpackager>
  <isofield
          id="49"
          length="3"
          name="Currency code, Transaction"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="50"
          length="3"
          name="Currency code, Reconciliation"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="51"
          length="3"
          name="Currency code, Cardholder billing"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="52"
          length="8"
          name="Personal identification number [PIN] data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
          id="53"
          length="48"
          name="Security related control information"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLBINARY"/>
  <isofield
          id="54"
          length="120"
          name="Amounts, additional"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="55"
          length="255"
          name="IC card system related data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY"/>
  <isofield
          id="56"
          length="35"
          name="Original data elements"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="57"
          length="3"
          name="Authorization life cycle code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="58"
          length="11"
          name="Authorizing agent institution Id Code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="59"
          length="999"
          name="Transport data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="60"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="61"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="62"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for private use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="63"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for private use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="64"
          length="8"
          name="Message authentication code field"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
          id="65"
          length="8"
          name="Reserved for ISO use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
          id="66"
          length="204"
          name="Amounts, original fees"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="67"
          length="2"
          name="Extended payment data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="68"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, receiving institution"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="69"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, settlement institution"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="70"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, authorizing agent Inst."
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="71"
          length="8"
          name="Message number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="72"
          length="999"
          name="Data record"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="73"
          length="6"
          name="Date, action"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="74"
          length="10"
          name="Credits, number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="75"
          length="10"
          name="Credits, reversal number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="76"
          length="10"
          name="Debits, number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="77"
          length="10"
          name="Debits, reversal number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="78"
          length="10"
          name="Transfer, number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="79"
          length="10"
          name="Transfer, reversal number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="80"
          length="10"
          name="Inquiries, number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="81"
          length="10"
          name="Authorizations, number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="82"
          length="10"
          name="Inquiries, reversal number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="83"
          length="10"
          name="Payments, number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="84"
          length="10"
          name="Payments, reversal number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="85"
          length="10"
          name="Fee collections, number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="86"
          length="16"
          name="Credits, amount"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="87"
          length="16"
          name="Credits, reversal amount"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="88"
          length="16"
          name="Debits, amount"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="89"
          length="16"
          name="Debits, reversal amount"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="90"
          length="10"
          name="Authorizations, reversal number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="91"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, transaction Dest. Inst."
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="92"
          length="3"
          name="Country code, transaction Orig. Inst."
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="93"
          length="11"
          name="Transaction Dest. Inst. Id code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="94"
          length="11"
          name="Transaction Orig. Inst. Id code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="95"
          length="99"
          name="Card issuer reference data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="96"
          length="999"
          name="Key management data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY"/>
  <isofield
          id="97"
          length="17"
          name="Amount, Net reconciliation"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield
          id="98"
          length="25"
          name="Payee"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="99"
          length="11"
          name="Settlement institution Id code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="100"
          length="11"
          name="Receiving institution Id code"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
          id="101"
          length="17"
          name="File name"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="102"
          length="28"
          name="Account identification 1"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="103"
          length="28"
          name="Account identification 2"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="104"
          length="100"
          name="Transaction description"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="105"
          length="16"
          name="Credits, Chargeback amount"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="106"
          length="16"
          name="Debits, Chargeback amount"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="107"
          length="10"
          name="Credits, Chargeback number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="108"
          length="10"
          name="Debits, Chargeback number"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
          id="109"
          length="84"
          name="Credits, Fee amounts"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="110"
          length="84"
          name="Debits, Fee amounts"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="111"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for ISO use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="112"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for ISO use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="113"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for ISO use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="114"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for ISO use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="115"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for ISO use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="116"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="117"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="118"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="119"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="120"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="121"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="122"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for national use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="123"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for private use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="124"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for private use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="125"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for private use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="126"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for private use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="127"
          length="999"
          name="Reserved for private use"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
          id="128"
          length="8"
          name="Message authentication code field"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
</isopackager>
```

here is the reponse i got :

```
Field 0
value 1804
Field 11
value 316535
Field 12
value 230401122323
Field 24
value 801
```

and the channel i use so far is PostChannel.
So i wonder if there is suitable Bitmap or Channel for this type of transactions in particular balance inquiry.

[image: Balance inquiry xml result]

and the input :

```
<log realm="packager" at="2023-04-03T20:25:30.021" 
lifespan="15ms">
  <unpack>
    31323030F032460108E10000000000001000000031363930343231323037373030353038313933313939393930303030303030303030303037343536303932333033303331363533343532333033303335333131323030313031323030303030303031303632343331313131303338343731323431353230303030303030323030303030303030303030303030313230636F6C6F6D62653938356D6163616D7061676E653031333730323038373635363730393831313930323336353239303637
    <bitmap>{1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 15, 18, 22, 23, 32, 37, 41, 42, 43, 48, 100}</bitmap>
    <unpack fld="2" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM">
      <!-- Primary Account number -->
      <value>9042120770050819</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="3" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <!-- Processing Code -->
      <value>319999</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="4" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <!-- Amount, Transaction -->
      <value>000000000000</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="11" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <!-- Systems trace audit number -->
      <value>745609</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="12" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <!-- Date and time, Local transaction -->
      <value>230303165345</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="15" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <!-- Date, Settlement -->
      <value>230303</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="18" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <!-- Merchant type -->
      <value>5311</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="22" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <!-- Point of service data code -->
      <value>200101200000</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="23" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <!-- Card sequence number -->
      <value>001</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="32" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM">
      <!-- Acquirer institution identification code -->
      <value>243111</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="37" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <!-- Retrieval reference number -->
      <value>103847124152</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="41" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <!-- Card acceptor terminal identification -->
      <value>00000002</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="42" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <!-- Card acceptor identification code -->
      <value>000000000000001</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="43" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR">
      <!-- Card acceptor name/location -->
      <value>colombe985macampagne</value>
    </unpack>
</log>
```

Comment: The channel and packager depend on the interface specifications, not on the type of message. Can you show the full request and response ISO msg xmls?

Comment: It's weird that they didn't answer the result code (DE 39) you have no way to know what is wrong with your message, and much less, most people here.